# Is it possible to bookmark lines in a notepad++ file using a pre-arranged content list from another file?

Tags: notepad++

I have a large XML file for McAfee IPS signatures and I need to remove a large chunk of signatures. I have a text file containing the names of the signatures I need to remove and I'm wondering if I can use that list to bookmark the correct lines in the XML file?

I've already used regex to get all the XML blocks into single lines and now I just need to find the appropriate lines.

Ex:
File 1 Contains
    attack  id="0xc0178200"  name="Example Name 1" /attack
    attack  id="0xc0178201"  name="Example Name 2" /attack
    attack  id="0xc0178202"  name="Example Name 3" /attack
    attack  id="0xc0178202"  name="Example Name 4" /attack
attack  id="0xc0178202"  name="Example Name 5" /attack
attack  id="0xc0178202"  name="Example Name 6" /attack

File 2 Contains:
Example Name 2
Example Name 5

The first file contains over 1000 signatures and I need to remove a couple hundred of them so being able to automate it would save me days worth of work. I want to use the list from file 2 to bookmark the XML blocks that contain those titles in file 1. Is this possible?

Comment: Why not write a script in your favorite scripting language?

Comment: Do you have GNU grep available?

Comment: @Toto do you have any examples?

Comment: Did you try something, what doesn't work?

Comment: @LarsFischer Sadly no but I can look into getting it. I'm guessing it does what I'm looking to do?

Comment: @Toto No, I haven't tried writing a script. I have access to Python but I wouldn't even know where to start.

Comment: Here is an algorithm: read file2 in an array, read file1 line by line, if the current line exists in array, do appropriate action.

Comment: @Toto I could give that a shot. Do you know off-hand how well Python works with regex?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Python, but I know it works prety fine with regex.

Comment: Alright awesome. I'll definitely give this a shot because I really don't want to have to do this by hand.

Comment: @RBD I think `grep -v -F -f file2 file1` would work.